# Clicking in dropdown closes it despite javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, drop-down-menu

Trying to create a list with collapsible headlines, however when I click inside the list it collapses.

Here's my javascript, (I don't know jQuery yet)

```
function comFunc() {
document.getElementById("Community").classList.toggle("show");

document.onclick = function(event) {
    var x = document.getElementById("Community");
    var y = document.getElementById("comarrow");

        if (x.classList.contains("show")) {
            y.classList.remove("glyphicon-menu-right");
            y.classList.add("glyphicon-menu-down");
        } else {
            y.classList.remove("glyphicon-menu-down");
            y.classList.add("glyphicon-menu-right");
            }
        }
window.onclick = function(event) {
        var x = document.getElementById("Community");
        var y = document.getElementById("comarrow");

        if (!event.target.matches('.resbtn')) {
            x.classList.remove('show');
            y.classList.remove("glyphicon-menu-down");
            y.classList.add("glyphicon-menu-right");
            }
        }
}
```

I tried to using "||" as in

```
if (!event.target.matches('.resbtn' || '.dropdown-content')) {
```

but that didn't seem to work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in [Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) you need a comma to combine the two selectors.

Hence, change from:

```
if (!event.target.matches('.resbtn' || '.dropdown-content')) {
```

to:

```
if (!event.target.matches('.resbtn, .dropdown-content')) {
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
   ele.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       var x = event.target.matches('.resbtn, .dropdown-content');
       console.log('matches=' + x + '\nhtml:' + this.outerHTML);
   });
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="resbtn">Click Me</button>
<button id="btn2" class="dropdown-content">Click Me</button>
<button id="btn3" class="noOne">Click Me</button>
```